# assign values to two variables after split

Tags: java, split

I have full name (ex : Robert King) separated by space in Database. I want to split the full name to FIRSTNAME and LASTNAME and assign it to two variables. How to achieve this in JAVA? I know it is simple but found it difficult to assign to two variable after split.

Comment: Can you show us what you think is easy and difficult by means of code samples?

Comment: You can't assign two variables at the same time. Just split in an array.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a didactic example:

```
/* String to split. */
String str = "Robert King";
String delimiter = " ";

String[] temp = str.split(delimiter);   
String name = temp[0];   
String surname = temp[1];
```

Comment: that's why I miss ruby  `name, surname = "Robert King".split`

Answer (score 10):

You can only assign to a single variable in java, so you'll need two steps:

```
String fullname = "Robert King";
String[] names = fullname.split(" ", 1); // "1" means stop splitting after one space
String firstName = names[0];
String lastName = names[1];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like below.

```
String firstName = fullName.split(" ")[0];
String lastName = fullName.split(" ")[1];
```

Hope this helps you. Cheers.

Comment: it's too prodigally to split it twice while you can do it only once

Comment: To add to @IgorKarbachinsky's comment, in Python, you could do it as:
`first_name, last_name = fullName.split(" ")`
Wish Java caught up.